# SSL Integration with apache used for load balancing

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat, load-balancing

We are using apache mod-proxy on top of tomcat to achive load balancing. It is working fine , now we are planning to move to https from httpd . For that 
my configuration looks as follows

```
NameVirtualHost 10.x.x.3:443

<VirtualHost 10.x.x.3:443>
ServerName 10.x.x.x.3

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On

ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/"

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
Header set Cache-Control no-cache
Header set Pragma no-cache

BalancerMember http://192.168.2.182:8080 route=node1
BalancerMember http://192.168.2.183:8080 route=node2

ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

I have added the certificate and key location in httpd-ssl.conf . Plz find below contents from httpd-ssl.conf

```
 Listen  43
 AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
 AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
 ErrorLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
 TransferLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log"
 SSLEngine on
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2


 SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5


 SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"

 <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
  SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
 </FilesMatch>
 <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
 SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
 </Directory>

 BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
     nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
     downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  CustomLog "/usr/local/apache2/logs/ssl_request_log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

 </VirtualHost>
```

https is working fine , but redirecting to tomcat servers is not happening. I am seeing the default apache "It works" test page .

Kindly guide am I missing anything in apache configuration

Comment: Might be as simple as the order in your configuration file, it looks at first glance that SSL is not yet configured when you define the virtual host. What happens when you move the `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` to the top of the snippet above?

Comment: Tried ..but no luck . Actually https is working fine but issue here is that when I implemented https , load balancing is not working which was working fine without SSL

Comment: Could you post the `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`. because if I look at my own ssl.conf include the majority of SSL setup is done within a virtualhost context and wouldn't neccesarily work in a second virtualhost.

Comment: The issue was resolved after I moved the load balancing configuration from httpd.conf to httpd-ssl.conf